# How do I change font color for a specific cell from UITableViewRowAction?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I added a custom button using UITAbleViewRowAction so when the user swipes left on a row, he/she sees the button. How do I get the button to change the font color for that specific row when he/she presses that button? Thanks!

Comment: Would you please show some code so we can see how you setup the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you implemented `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?`, then you can do this inside your action:

```
let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Action") { (action, indexPath) in
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .red
    tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
}
return [action]
```

If you've subclassed `UITableViewCell`, then you'll have to do

`let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MySubclassTableViewCell`

and edit the appropiate label inside your class.

Alternatively, you could store the indexPath outside of the closure and reload the tableView.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I was trying to use tableView(tableView: cellForRowAt:) instead of tableView.cellForRow (at:). Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to here ;) Always remember that `tableView(tableView: cellForRowAt:)` is the `UITableViewDataSource` method you implement to tell the tableView the cells it has to use. `tableView.cellForRow(at:)` lets you access those cells.